# Post и Controller

Tags: controller, yii, post

Вот таким вот макаром обращаюсь к файлику

```
 jQuery.post(
 "/mysite/protected/views/site/appview/showmore.php",
 {},
 function(data)
     {  
       if(data!="stop")
       {
         jQuery("#content").append(data);
       }
     }   );
```

В файле showmore.php нужно вызвать метод `ShowContent()`, который описан в `SiteController`.

`$this->ShowContent()` здесь не прокатит, что делать?

Comment: старайтесь делать так, что бы protected был вне корневой директории

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лучше бы вы не напрямую к файлику обращались, а отправляли запрос по роуту. Так было бы правильно. К тому же вы пытаетесь отправить запрос шаблону а не контроллеру. Это в корне не правильно.

Допустим у вас SiteController и в нем экшн - actionShowContent.
Для этого экшна в конфиге пропишите роут вида - site/showcontent.
И тогда из JS можно отправить запрос так:

```
jQuery.post(
    "/site/showcontent",
    {},
    function(data)
    { 
        if(data!="stop"){
            jQuery("#content").append(data);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: @Barton здесь же?
>'log'=>array(
   'class'=>'CLogRouter',
   'routes'=>array(

Comment: вот здесь описано как добавить роут: http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.url

Comment: @Barton спасибо! Все получилось